Characterisation of Bessel process
Let $\delta \in (0, 2)$; $(X_t)_{t \ge 0}$ a nonnegative continuous Markov process. Suppose that

For each $T \ge 0$, if we write $\tau \overset{\mathrm{def}}= \inf\{t \ge T : X_t = 0\}$, then $(X_{T + t})_{t \in [0, \tau - T]}$ has the law of a Bessel process of dimension $\delta$, starting from $X_T$, and stopped upon hitting $0$.
The set $\{t \ge 0 : X_t = 0\}$ has Lebesgue measure $0$.

Do we then have $X$ is a Bessel process of dimension $\delta$?
